# Credentials for ethstats (main-net)

Tags: ethstats

I am searching for a way to get credentials for ethstats on the main-nets. I found some references that you could get them on a skype-channel. Would love to not use skype - is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Skype is the only way to get the `WS_SECRET`.

You simply join the [skype channel](http://tinyurl.com/ofndjbo) and the `WS_SECRET` will be the name/id of the channel. You do not need to stay in the channel for it to work -- just copy the ID, close skype, and paste it in the `app.json` file that comes with the Network-Status github project.

Once you filled it all in, run an instance of [Network-Status](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Network-Status) by executing `pm2 start app.json` after you've cloned the project from github.

Comment: Thanks - I do not really like the fact you have to use skype (kind of a blocker for me) - but accept it anyway as it seems to be the correct answer